# Minio with helm install (distributed mode), how to do configuration for the volume and HA in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, distributed, high-availability, minio

I have installed minio in my kubernetes using helm and 4 nodes are running
[root@bastion-nks-lab ~]# kc get pods -n digimops
NAME              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
minio-cluster-0   1/1     Running   0          27h

minio-cluster-1   1/1     Running   0          27h

minio-cluster-2   1/1     Running   0          27h

minio-cluster-3   1/1     Running   0          27h

How to do the configuration for volume in the distributed mode and high availability | someone share the step by step configuration for minio with distribution mode with HA